# Restrict the page to be browsed in the other browser with the same urls

Tags: login-control, browser-security

how to restrict the page to be browsed in the  other browser with the same urls with out logging asp.net & c#.net.

i followed the following steps
for example:

1. i am logging in to a page developed in asp.net & c#.net.
2. i am viewing a page.Let it be admin page.
3. i am  copying the url of the admin page.
4. i am opening another browser window and pasting the url.
5. i was able to see the same admin page in the other browser.

the question is how to restrict the opening of admin page in other browser,if they try to open admin page in another browser while user is currently viewing the admin page then it should  be redirected to the login page?
how could this be accomplished? 
is there any thing could be done with "login" control tool of the .net frame work?

Answer (score 0):

- If you copy the URL, close the browser, open it up again and paste the URL does it still work?
- If you copy the URL, email it to a friend who pastes it in to *their* browser, does it still work?

I don't think you need to do anything special here, this is just how sessions work. As long as the two cases above do not work, of course...

Comment: i am  copying the first browser url and not closing the first browser browser and opening another new window in the same system and pasting on second browser is opening the same page,it should not open.And the first browser is not still closed

Comment: If you don't close the first browser, when you open the second window, it's still the same browser *process* and hence the same session. Try it with any other website where you "log in", it'll be the same.